# Authorize.net, charge credit card request gives error as A duplicate transaction has been submitted

Tags: xml, authorize.net

I am new to Authorize.Net, I am implementing Authorize.Net PHP SDK to implement it. I am trying to charge a credit card but it is giving error as:

> "A duplicate transaction has been submitted"

I read several articles, reference : https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/Prevent-Duplicate-Transactions/td-p/20417.

where the solution mentioned that add *x_duplicate_window = (of your own choice, maximum 28800 seconds)* to your script.
so I added it as follows:

```
<createTransactionRequest xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
    <merchantAuthentication>
        <name>
            <![CDATA[API_LOGIN_ID]]>
        </name>
        <transactionKey>
            <![CDATA[API_TRANSACTION_KEY]]>
        </transactionKey>
    </merchantAuthentication>
    <refId>
        <![CDATA[ref1465541052]]>
    </refId>
    <transactionRequest>
        <transactionType>
            <![CDATA[authCaptureTransaction]]>
        </transactionType>
        <amount>1</amount>
        <payment>
            <creditCard>
                <cardNumber>
                    <![CDATA[4111111111111111]]>
                </cardNumber>
                <expirationDate>
                    <![CDATA[1233]]>
                </expirationDate>
            </creditCard>
        </payment>
        <order>
            <description>
                <![CDATA[DESCRIPTION]]>
            </description>
        </order>
    </transactionRequest>
    <extraOptions><![CDATA[x_duplicate_window=0]]></extraOptions>
</createTransactionRequest>
```

but it throws error as

> E00003 : The element 'createTransactionRequest' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd' has invalid child element 'extraOptions' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd'.

I am unable to add *x_duplicate_window* in my script. 
Is this the right way to prevent duplicate transaction error

> NOTE: I'm working in sandbox environment and at LIVE mode

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `<transactionSettings>` element to add this setting:

```
<createTransactionRequest xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
    <merchantAuthentication>
        <name>
            <![CDATA[API_LOGIN_ID]]>
        </name>
        <transactionKey>
            <![CDATA[API_TRANSACTION_KEY]]>
        </transactionKey>
    </merchantAuthentication>
    <refId>
        <![CDATA[ref1465541052]]>
    </refId>
    <transactionRequest>
        <transactionType>
            <![CDATA[authCaptureTransaction]]>
        </transactionType>
        <amount>1</amount>
        <payment>
            <creditCard>
                <cardNumber>
                    <![CDATA[4111111111111111]]>
                </cardNumber>
                <expirationDate>
                    <![CDATA[1233]]>
                </expirationDate>
            </creditCard>
        </payment>
        <order>
            <description>
                <![CDATA[DESCRIPTION]]>
            </description>
        </order>
        <transactionSettings>
            <setting>
                <settingName>duplicateWindow</settingName>
                <settingValue>0</settingValue>
            </setting>
        </transactionSettings>
    </transactionRequest>
</createTransactionRequest>
```

Comment: Just wanted to ask, if we can change value of 'duplicateWindow', then why its has been set to 2 minutes. If I change value of 'duplicateWindow', will it violet my transaction id or something?

Comment: It defaults to two minutes but you are given the opportunity to supersede it if necessary as each business has different business rules. Changing it doesn't affect anything other then how long you have to wait to run a duplicate transaction.